# Writing a GlusterFS Translator - Any Documentation about this?

Tags: c, linux, filesystems

I would like to write a custom GlusterFS Translator for file encryption with AES. Besides this rather rare description: 
http://europe.gluster.org/community/documentation/index.php/GlusterFS_Contributors_FAQ, is there any other documentation on writing a custom Translator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe HekaFS is what you need, it already has a encryption translator.

Answer (score 1):

You can find some dated documentation in the hacker-guide directory of the source repository:

http://git.gluster.com/?p=glusterfs.git;a=tree;f=doc/hacker-guide;hb=HEAD

hacker-guide.tex should be a good place to start.

Comment: Thanks, haven't seen that file so far. It gives you some ideas, but though the documentation is very bad. An explanation of the fops and mops would be good!

Answer (score 1):

There is a detailed talk on this topic from #oscon12, which is being recorded today, from RedHat ,also suggest you download the slides

Here's a [link](http://www.oscon.com/oscon2012/public/schedule/detail/26496) to the presentation slides